# Constructor error: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant

Tags: c++, dictionary, constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::shared_ptr<std::string> StrPtr;
auto hash1 = [](const StrPtr ptr) { return std::hash<std::string>()(*ptr); };

...

class Actor {

    ...

    private:
        std::unordered_multimap<StrPtr,StrPtr,decltype(hash1)> set(250000,hash1);
    ...
};
```

If I want to compile it I get the following error:

```
Actor.hpp:15:68: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     std::unordered_multimap<StrPtr,StrPtr,decltype(hash1)> set(250000,hash1);
                                                                ^
Actor.hpp:15:68: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

Looking at the constructor definition of unordered_multimap, there seems to be no contradiction to my initialization. What is the problem here?

I compiled with gcc 4.8

Comment: IIRC, if you want to have inline initialization you need to use curly-brackets `{}`. Also, remember that GCC 4.8 is old and doesn't support all of C++11, so it might not support inline initialization at all.

Comment: I believe the compiler gets very confused because it thinks you're declaring a member function.

Comment: Using `gcc version 5.3.1` gives the same result. Still I don't get why this isn't valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular parentheses are not allowed in a brace-or-equals initializer. Use curly brackets:

```
std::unordered_multimap<StrPtr,StrPtr,decltype(hash1)> set{250000,hash1};
```

This limitation prevents ambiguity that would arise in some cases with function declarations, which use parenthesis.

Comment: Ok, that "worked". But now I'm getting the warning: `warning: ‘Actor’ has a field ‘Actor::set’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace
 class Actor` which I don't understand. And by the way, is it possible to use the initialization with regular parentheses inside a funtion. Because I originally saw this example in a book, where this construction with regular parantheses was used inside a function.

Comment: Correct. Regular parenthesis can be used when initializing a local variable, but not in a brace-or-equals initializer. If you have a new problem, and don't manage to solve it, post a new question with a [mcve]

Comment: Better not, if I'd post another question, which doesn't get upvoted, I'm running out of my questions limit too soon.

Comment: @FloriHe: What "questions limit"? Unless you've deleted a lot of downvoted questions, you're nowhere even near a question ban. If you have a new question you should ask it as such (after attempting to solve the problem yourself and performing the customary research, of course). This is not a chatroom or discussion forum, so ongoing conversation/question-asking should not take place here.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Well I think it's better to do my own research instead of immediately asking a new question. Don't you know the question limit?

Comment: @FloriHe: Yes, I literally just said that. And there is no "question limit"; where did you hear that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/stack-overflow-you-have-reached-your-question-limit

Comment: @FloriHe: Now read the answers to that question. It's not a "question limit"; the OP got banned. Unless you have deleted them all, you have _no_ negative-scored questions, and are thus nowhere even remotely close to a question ban.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well I heard from a person, who: `got one question deleted by the admins (with a negative score on it)`, `got one question with -2 vote` and `got 6 question with 0 vote` and got a question "ban" for six months. On the page it is written: 
`You have reached your question limit`. So, this question and my last question got both a zero vote, which means I should be careful not to ask too quickly in foresight not to suffer the same fate.

Comment: @FloriHe: That person was lying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ehm no, he isn't. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans . The relevant part is:  `users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts.` . So this is exactly the pattern which led to his question ban/"limit reach"

Comment: @FloriHe: "Significant". Three is not significant. You are nowhere near a question ban. Not sure why you are so inclined to distrust a 230k user who's been getting to know this system for six years, but hey ho.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm not distrusting you. I just try not to be too reckless in asking questions. If you aren't a high-performer then there is question-ban looming if you keep asking too much basic stuff.